# Xcode 7 beta 4: MKMapKit hangs the app

Tags: ios, mapkit, xcode7, xcode7-beta4

I'm seeing a strange problem with Xcode 7 beta 4 and the iOS 9 simulator. Any app that uses a map hangs when trying to load the view containing the map. It does not throw an exception. If I remove the map, it works. This appears to have a 100% repro, even in a very simple project.

When a map is present, I see the following log output:

> /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1134.11/GeoCSS/GeoCSS/StyleSheet.cpp:122
>   STYL Parse: Decode error here
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1134.11/GeoCSS/GeoCSS/StyleSheet.cpp:99
>   STYL Parse: Decode error here

A coworker with the same setup doesn't have any problems with the same project.

Comment: Works fine here in the simulator but one of our testers devices would always lock up the second the app loaded. All devices and simulators run iOS 8.4, that doesn't make a difference at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem should be solved with Xcode 7 beta 5. Just download and install the latest build!

Comment: The beta 5 indeed fixes the problem!

Comment: The Update (Version 7.0 beta 5 (7A176x)) didn't fixed it for me, still getting the same error BlackRider had!

Comment: Same.. may be an IB issue?

Comment: not working for me could anyone have solution for this?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7.0 beta 6. Getting same error still.

/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/VectorKit-1134.11/GeoCSS/GeoCSS/StyleSheet.cpp:122 STYL Parse: Decode error here.
Any Solution?

Comment: no @AshokKumarS I didn't find any solution. Once I will get any update let you know but incase if you get any update please update me

Comment: @TENSRI. Check my answer below. - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

'**Xcode7.0 GM seed**' is solved this issue.
I was facing this issue even with '**Xcode7.0 GM seed**', later i came to know that, the device i'm using has a older version of iOS9 beta. I have updated it to latest version and the issue is automatically solved.
So, make sure the device also has latest beta version.
 Check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472735/xcode-7-0-beta-6-issue-with-vectorkit).
-Thanks