# Xcode 7.0 beta 6: Issue with VectorKit

Tags: ios, mapkit, xcode7, xcode7-beta6

I'm using MapKit in my App. Everything is fine except with iOS9.
I recently downloaded **Xcode7.0 beta 6** and ran my project in **iOS9 beta**, App is hanged with the following error message in console:

> /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/VectorKit-
>   1134.11/GeoCSS/GeoCSS/StyleSheet.cpp:122 STYL Parse: Decode error here /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/VectorKit-1134.11/GeoCSS/GeoCSS/StyleSheet.cpp:99
>   STYL Parse: Decode error here

Anyone know what is causing the issue?
Thanks.

**Update:**
Checked with '**Xcode7.0 GM seed**' today, the problem is still there.
 Anyone facing same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'**Xcode7.0 GM seed**' is solved my problem.
The problem is, the device i'm using has a old iOS9 Beta[It was **9.0(13A4254v)**], Now i have updated it to '**iOS9 GM**' **9.0(13A340)**.
The issue is automatically solved.

FYI, 
To install iOS9 Beta in device, please refer the [link](http://www.redmondpie.com/ios-9-beta-download-release-date-features-and-rumors-update/)

Comment: sorry could you please tell me how to download iOS 9 Beta?

Comment: @TENSRI, Please check my updated answer. Feel free to let me know, if you are not able to solve your problem.

Comment: woww super @Ashok Kumar S I have fixed it with your help and upvoted for your help. :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Purchase iPhone6S with iOS 9.0 today.  Xcode 7.0 (7A220).

I get same error:

"ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/VectorKit-1156.1.6/src/karo/media/image/jpegloaderfig.mm 95: Failed to decode JPEG image with hardware decoder. "

Any suggestions how to make it work with no BETAs installed?  Thanks